# Access Azure through http on non-standard port

Tags: azure

I have a Azure vm with Windows 2012 R2 and some hotfixes.

I`ve installed Tomcat on the VM and set it up to be accessible on a non-standard port.
9060.

When accessing, I get no page displayed.

http://myservice.cloudapp.net:9060 is not reachable nor is anything displayed.

http://myservice.cloudapp.net for port 80 also is not acessible.

Other posts suggest enabling ports, which I have done, but still no success.

Any thoughts?

regards sanjay

Answer (score 2):

In addition to opening the port in the windows firewall you'll need to [add an endpoint to the VM](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/).